# How to install and use Powerdevil on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, power-management, system-settings

I'm quite new to Ubuntu so sorry if there is something obvious I have been missing. The thing is, I have a laptop and thus want to use power saving options. However, in GNOME, as far as I can tell, I can only manage general settings and not define what to do for High Battery / Low Battery / Powered mode individually. Thus, I stumbled upon KDE's power management. I tried to get Powerdevil via
    sudo apt-get install powerdevil
and it downloaded and installed everything fine. The problem I am now facing is the following: The settings haven't changed at all, thus I assume I'll have to tell GNOME first that it should use powerdevil instead of its own tools. Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: TLP can be used or PowerTop. I have no time now for deeper explanation, thatswhy just a comment so that you can search and find a solution.